# Removing `~` in `~/my_repo/~`

Tags: linux, shell, command-line, directory

I made a mistake in my code and a *funky* home directory appear in my project repo directory. It seems that the `~` folder under my repo is not a symbolic link, so I don't feel safe to do `rm ~/myrepo/~`.

**Note: when I do `cd ~/my_repo/~`, `pwd` gives me `/home/alex`, which is my home directory.**

**Is there a way to remove it safely?**

[image]

Comment: `rm -rf ~/my_repo/~` should be safe ... feel free to experiment by creating a tmp-dir somewhere else and blow it away there

Comment: When I do `cd ~/my_repo/~`, `pwd` gives me `/home/alex`, which is my home directory.

Comment: Odd ... what distro are you on, what shell are you using?  In `bash 4.3.48` on Ubuntu 16.04 this all just works.

Answer (score 1):

Quote or escape the `~` that you want to use literally.

```
cd ~/my_repo/\~
rm -rf ~/my_repo/'~'
```

Comment: The only thing that I am worrying is whether it will remove my home directory? Since it is exactly the same directory.

Comment: It's not the same directory. Bash treats `~/foo/~` as equivalent to just `~`, but quoting it prevents that.

Comment: Use `ls -R` to see what it will remove.